# How to add user input data to some fields in crystal reports using push method with other relational tables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report file with header and footer placeholders. The report is connected with 3 tables. 2 tables are connected with foreign key and the 3rd table is only information of the company or other data which will be get on runtime from user acquired and in DataSet saved.
How can I join these three tables. Because it refuses to put tables on one report without relationship between all of them.

Need some more guidance on what could be done here to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you can try is to use `Sub reports`.

Take the `table` that is isolated in sub report and other two tables that are connected with foreign key in main report.

By this you can solve the issue.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks for reply. but do you think is it a good solution for only company information and logo for each report to create a sub report ??

Comment: To the extent I dont think there is no other solution also sub report is a good option.... one sub report doesn't efffect toomuch.... performance effected if there are multiple sub reports

Comment: thanks Siva, but please if i need to several parts in the report, which they are not related ? how can i do that ?

Comment: Didn't get your requirement. ...several parts means? Can you elaborate a bit more

Comment: i mean the report is consisting of 4 parts (top, middle, right, left) . In the top, it is company data(from db also but isolated table), left some other data and also right. In middle some tables which they have relations to each other.

Comment: Yes its possible. ..in a sub report...pass top part data from main report....  left, right and bottom calculate in sub report internally

Comment: Thanks Siva for your help. i would be very thankful if you write me where can i find good crystal report reference. i am searching for one from a long time

Comment: There are no specific books that I am aware of on crystal reports.... I learnt just by practising... :)

Answer (score 1):

First Point Is there Any Common Columns Between the  Table ?

if Not Insert One table That contain Columns Between the table

then It will Automatically Link all the Tables

Comment: thanks for your reply. basically i don't want to link the table. For example Master/Detail tables + Company information table. the last one has no relation or link with the first two tables. that what i mean. do you have any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: According to Crystal reports or Business Objects  No table should be kept Isolated ;